# Visual C++ Odeint integrate_const no matching overloaded function

Tags: c++, templates, boost, odeint

I'm trying to use `integrate_const` in Visual C++, as part of a class with an overloaded `operator()`. Why is the compiler failing to specialize the template?

```
size_t steps = boost::numeric::odeint::integrate_const(stepper, *this, x, tbegin, tfinal, dt, obs);
```

I'm getting IntelliSense and compilation errors saying:

> no instance of overloaded function
>   "boost::numeric::odeint::integrate_const" matches the argument
>   list      c:\Users\...\src\duffing.cpp   81

Further, it gives the message:

> Error C2893   Failed to specialize function template 'size_t
>   boost::numeric::odeint::integrate_const(Stepper,System,const State
>   &,Time,Time,Time,Observer)'   aimsexamples    C:\Users\...\src\duffing.cpp   81
>   Error C2893   Failed to specialize function template 'size_t
>   boost::numeric::odeint::integrate_const(Stepper,System,State
>   &,Time,Time,Time,Observer)'   aimsexamples    C:\Users\...\src\duffing.cpp   81

---

**ADDITIONAL INFO** (edited):

**Header**

```
typedef std::vector<double> state_type;

struct push_back_state_and_time
{
    std::vector< state_type >& m_states;
    std::vector< double >& m_times;

    push_back_state_and_time(std::vector< state_type > &states, std::vector< double > &times)
        : m_states(states), m_times(times) { }

    void operator()(const state_type &x, double t)
    {
        m_states.push_back(x);
        m_times.push_back(t);
    }
};

class duffingmodel: public forwardmodel
{

private:
    uint64_t num_timesteps;
    double dt;
    std::vector<double> param;
    // 'params' is accessible from 'operator()'
    // the argument to loglikelihood is copied into 'params'
    std::vector<double> data;  
    // 'data' populated in constructor
    // loglikelihood compares a simulation done with different parameters with entries in 'data'
public:
    duffingmodel(duffingmodelbuilder const &); // Populates 'data'
    double loglikelihood(std::vector<double> const &); // Calls the 'integrate_const'
    void operator()(state_type const &, state_type &, const double); // state-derivative
};
```

**Implementation**

```
// state-derivative operator
void duffingmodel::operator()(state_type const &x, state_type &dxdt, const double /*t*/)
{

    dxdt[0] = x[1];
    dxdt[1] = -this->param[0] * x[1] - this->param[1] * x[0] - this->param[2] * pow(x[0], 3) + this->param[3] * cos(x[2]);
    dxdt[2] = this->param[4];
}

// function that does the calculations
double duffingmodel::loglikelihood(std::vector<double> const &s)
{
    uint64_t n; // Iterator
    double term, val = 0.0;

    state_type x(3);
    std::vector<double> times;
    std::vector<state_type> x_vec;

    x[0] = s[5];
    x[1] = s[6];
    x[2] = 0.0;

    double tbegin = 0.0;
    double tfinal = ((double)(this->num_timesteps - 1)) * this->dt;
    double dt = this->dt;
    this->param = s;

    boost::numeric::odeint::runge_kutta4<state_type> stepper;

    // *** Offending line of code ***    
    size_t steps = boost::numeric::odeint::integrate_const(stepper, *this, x, tbegin, tfinal, dt, push_back_state_and_time(x_vec, times));

    // Just calculations...not relevant to the integral
    for (n = 0u; n < this->num_timesteps; n++)
    {
        term = data[n] - x_vec[n][0];
        val += term * term;
    }

    val = 0.5 * val * exp(-2.0 * s[7]);
    val += -0.5 * (double) (this->num_timesteps) * log(2.0 * M_PI) - (double) (this->num_timesteps) * s[7];

    return val;
}
```

**Calling program**

```
int main()
{
    // Create a builder struct and populate its members
    duffingbuilder a;
    a.dt = 0.01;
    a.num_timesteps = 1000;
    a.dataxinit = 0.0; 
    a.datavinit = 0.0; 
    a.dataalpha = 1.0; 
    a.databeta = 0.0;
    // etc etc

    // Construct the duffingmodel
    duffingmodel x(a);

    // Define a point at which to evaluate the loglikelihood member
    std::vector<double> p(8);
    p[0] = 1.01;
    // p[1] = ...;
    //...
    p[7] = -1.0;

    double ll = duffingmodel.loglikelihood(p);

    // Print everything out
    std::cout << "Likelihood f(D;p) = " << p << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

---

Compiler Errors

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2672   'boost::numeric::odeint::integrate_const': no matching overloaded function found    aimsexamples    C:\Users\Pinaky\Desktop\aims-2016\aimsexamples\src\duffing.cpp  81  
Error   C2780   'size_t boost::numeric::odeint::integrate_const(Stepper,System,const State &,Time,Time,Time)': expects 6 arguments - 7 provided aimsexamples    C:\Users\Pinaky\Desktop\aims-2016\aimsexamples\src\duffing.cpp  81  
Error   C2780   'size_t boost::numeric::odeint::integrate_const(Stepper,System,State &,Time,Time,Time)': expects 6 arguments - 7 provided   aimsexamples    C:\Users\Pinaky\Desktop\aims-2016\aimsexamples\src\duffing.cpp  81  
Error   C2893   Failed to specialize function template 'size_t boost::numeric::odeint::integrate_const(Stepper,System,const State &,Time,Time,Time,Observer)'   aimsexamples    C:\Users\Pinaky\Desktop\aims-2016\aimsexamples\src\duffing.cpp  81  
Error   C2893   Failed to specialize function template 'size_t boost::numeric::odeint::integrate_const(Stepper,System,State &,Time,Time,Time,Observer)' aimsexamples    C:\Users\Pinaky\Desktop\aims-2016\aimsexamples\src\duffing.cpp  81  
Error   C2780   'size_t boost::numeric::odeint::integrate_const(Stepper,System,const State &,Time,Time,Time,Observer,StepOverflowChecker)': expects 8 arguments - 7 provided    aimsexamples    C:\Users\Pinaky\Desktop\aims-2016\aimsexamples\src\duffing.cpp  81  
Error   C2780   'size_t boost::numeric::odeint::integrate_const(Stepper,System,State &,Time,Time,Time,Observer,StepOverflowChecker)': expects 8 arguments - 7 provided  aimsexamples    C:\Users\Pinaky\Desktop\aims-2016\aimsexamples\src\duffing.cpp  81
```

Comment: It seems you are passing `const State&` as the third parameter, but the signature requires `State&`. Are you sure that the `typedef` does not contain `const` or you are taking `x` from a `const` method/instance?

Comment: My `typedef` for `state_type` contains no `const`. By the way, There's an overload for `integrate_const` that takes as argument `const State &`. Compare the 2nd and 3rd declarations here:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/numeric/odeint/doc/html/header/boost/numeric/odeint/integrate/integrate_const_hpp.html.

Comment: Can you show the operator()? this might be the part where things go wrong.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example showing the problem, so we can check if this is a problem specific to msvc?

Comment: Added `operator()` details. I doubt that this is the problem, though. Working on minimum example. Any common, possibly relevant MSVC quirks?

Comment: Well, it's not really a minimum *working* example, but should illustrate what's going on. `forwardmodel` is just an abstract class with a pure virtual member `loglikelihood`

Comment: Can you reduce the example even more such that it consists only of a single file containing everything?

Comment: Huh: a new project with the single file doesn't have issues with the `integrate_const` overload. It compiles just fine. Here's a gist for you (so others can still read the original code; I understand that this link may expire): https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a5cc82c50946c1cda15cd99bcbd282af
I wonder what the problem with my original project is. It still has the same error.

Comment: Are there more compiler outputs? It might be possible that the list of possible overloads is shown.

Comment: Added all the compiler outputs associated with the error (the same error shows up in another function). Here is a gist of the full compiler output:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/2ee57636a2d4ad255345f4a90c134010